# Step value in Pascal programming

Tags: pascal

I want a programming code to print the odd numbers between a range to teach the students. Here I took the range as 1 to 10. So I want to print the odd numbers between 1 to 10.

I wrote this coding to print the odd numbers between 1 to 10

```
program printOdd1to10; {Prints odd numbers 1 - 10}

var counter : integer;
begin

   for counter := 1 to 10 do

      begin
        Writeln(counter); {prints new line}
        counter := counter + 2 {increment by value 2, like step 2}
      end;
        Readln;

end.
```

But when I run, it prints a long series of wrong answer.
So, how to print like this pattern odd, even, times of 3(3,6,9...) numbers in pascal programming.

Comment: Use the `Odd()` function or `(counter and 1 <> 0)` or `(counter mod 2 <> 0)` to get the odd numbers. Don't ever think of changing the loop counter inside the loop.

Comment: So, how to get times of 3 (3,6,9,...) or times of N ?

Comment: You can loop from 1 to 10 and test for Odd, no problem.

Comment: No, that is OK to check odd no. or even no. But how to print multiplication of number N in a specific range ?

For eg: multiplication of 5, from 5 to 60.
(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60).

Comment: oh! Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I removed my comment, since you actually mentioned the requirement to have more patterns. Then just use the modulo operator: `if counter mod x = 0 then`.

Comment: Use your imagination and do what others do: `for i := 1 to max div step do Writeln(i*step);` If, for instance, `step = 5` and `max = 60`, that will give you `5, 10, ... 60`.

Comment: @Rudy nice answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following Jeff's answer, the best way to code your program is with 'while'.

```
i:= 1;  // start with an odd number
while i < 10 do
 begin
  writeln (i);
  i:= i + 2;  // or inc (i, 2)
 end;
```

Incrementing i by 2 each time will ensure that i is always odd, so there's no need to check this.

Answer (score 4):

The `for` statement in Pascal does not support a step value, and you shouldn't alter the value of the index variable (this is a general principle for programming). Either test the index variable's value for the condition you are interested in (e.g., `if odd(counter) then...`), or re-code as a `while` or `repeat...until` loop, where you can have a 'pseudo-index' variable that you can manipulate as you feel necessary.

Comment: if (counter mod 2 = 1) then, is this ok ?

Comment: Yes. The key issue is not to _change_ the value of the index variable of a loop. _Using_ the value as though it were read-only, and calculating with it to produce a value for a different variable or expression, is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so familiar with pascal. But, I have a suggestion for you, what about using conditional to check the number if it divides into 2 with remaining of 1 (Like 5/2 and the remaining is 1) and then print it.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: 'for counter := 1 to 10 do '
begin
if (counter mod 2 = 1) then
writeln(counter);
end;

Comment: Program whileLoop;
var
   a: integer;

begin
   a := 0;
   while  a < 20  do
   begin
   a := a + 1;
  if(a mod 2 = 1 ) then 
   writeln('value of a: ', a);
  
   end;
end. This is how it worked for me. I used online compiler